# what does lists = list(zip(*reader)) do in python

Tags: python, dataset, visualization

```py
import csv

with open('cleaned_all_phones.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    
    lists = list(zip(*reader))
    
    for row in lists:
      #prints y axis
        print(row[0])
      #print x axis 
        print(row[697])
```

just trying print out a large dataset using csv

Comment: `reader` is a list of iterables,`*reader` unpacks them as separate arguments for `zip`, zip takes element `n` of each iterable and creates a tuple and creates an iterable of those tuples

Comment: Can you please add the structure of the csv , like columns in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, reader will be an iterable of **rows** of the table your csv represents, and list(zip(*reader)) will be a list of **columns** of this table.

Comment: It's transposing the list of rows into a list of columns

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the csv.reader object, reader contains rows of the CSV file.

When you iterate over the reader object, each iteration yields a row from the CSV file as a list of strings.

*reader would then unpack then one by one, each row.
zip(*reader) would pack each element of the row into a tuple. Now each element of the rows is basically a column.

So if your CSV had data like:

```py
a1, a2, a3
b1, b2, b3
c1, c2, c3
```

The result of list(zip(*reader)) would be something like:

```py
[(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2), (a3, b3, c3)]
```